# delete a pointer in std::vector exposed by boost::python

Tags: python, c++, boost, stdvector, boost-python

I have these two classes:

```
typedef std::vector<Entity *> EntityPtrVector;

class A
{
private:
    EntityPtrVector entity_vector;

public:
    void AddEntity(Entity *);
    void RemoveEntity(std::string);
};

class Entity
{
private:
    std::string name_;

public:
    Entity();
    Entity(std::string);

    std::string GetName(void) const { return name_; }
    void SetName(const std::string& name) { name_ = name; }
};
```

I expose them by boost::python like this:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(my_lib)
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    class_<EntityPtrVector>("EntityPtrVector")
        .def(vector_indexing_suite<EntityPtrVector>());

    class_<A>("A", init<std::string>())
        .def("AddEntity", &A::AddEntity)
        .def("RemoveEntity", &A::RemoveEntity)
    ;

    class_<Entity>("Entity", init<std::string>())
        .add_property("name", &Entity::GetName, &Entity::SetName)
    ;
}
```

The implementations of `AddEntity` and `RemoveEntity` are:

```
void Game::AddEntity(Entity *E)
{
    entity_vector.push_back(E);
}

void Game::RemoveEntity(std::string entity_name)
{
    EntityPtrVector::iterator entity_ptr;

    // Find the entity with the input name
    for(entity_ptr = entity_vector.begin(); entity_ptr != entity_vector.end(); ++entity_ptr)
    {
        if((*entity_ptr)->GetName() == entity_name)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    // Remove the target entity
    if(entity_ptr != entity_vector.end())
    {
        delete *entity_ptr;
        entity_vector.erase(entity_ptr);
    }
}
```

I have already checked that it works under C++ without exposed to python. In python, the parts of `AddEntity` and finding target entity are success, but it crashes at the `delete *` instruction of `RemoveEntity` (I check these by adding log instructions after each line of the codes). This is my test code in python:

```
import my_lib

test_a = my_lib.A("Test A")
test_e = my_lib.Entity("Test Entity")

test_a.AddEntity(test_e)
test_a.RemoveEntity("Test Entity")
```

I think maybe I do the exposing of `std::vector<Entity *>` Incorrectly, but how can I correct this?

Comment: Why have you used HTML/JavaScript runnable code snippet blocks for C++ and Python?

Comment: Can you make a testcase? Perhaps abstract away all the Python? And what did your debugger say?

Comment: There is no proof in your code that shows that your entities were dynamically allocated, so calling `delete` would result in undefined behavior on non-dynamically allocated entries.

Comment: Oh, thanks PaulMcKenzie and Yakk, maybe I know what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test_e = my_lib.Entity("Test Entity")
```

creates a Python object that owns the C++ `Entity`.  It manages the lifetime.

```
test_a.AddEntity(test_e)
```

here we pass the C++ object wrapped by `test_e` to the C++ object wrapped by `test_a`.  The C++ object is stored within the vector of the `A`.

```
test_a.RemoveEntity("Test Entity")
```

this deletes the `Entity` you added above.  However, the `test_e` class *still thinks it owns the `Entity`, as there is no way for it to be told you passed ownership away.  But now it owns an invalid pointer.

The crash happens at the delete because C++ isn't managing that memory -- python is.  It doesn't use the C++ heap.

You need to have a firmer design for ownership and lifetime management in the C++ code.  Never `delete` what you did not `new`, and the C++ code in the python case never `new`ed that `Entity`.

Comment: That is, for example, I need a member function which can new a Entity and return the point of it in C++, then give this point to AddEntity right?

Comment: @Ddavid you need to stop passing around ownership of objects via raw C++ pointers.  Use typed owning smart pointers if you have ownership.  Then make the interfaces work in Python.